# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' - using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am a newbie to Python here is my code:

```
#!venv/bin/python
import sys
import requests
import bs4

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
# If arguments are satisfied store them in readable variables
url = 'http://%s' % sys.argv[1]
file_name = sys.argv[2]

print('Grabbing the page...')
# Get url from command line
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve all links on the page
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')

file = open(file_name, 'wb')
print('Collecting the links...')
for link in links:
    href=link.get("href") + "\n"
    file.write(href.encode())
file.close()
print('Saved to %s' % file_name)
else:
print('Usage: ./collect_links.py www.example.com file.txt')
```

I'm facing the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collect_links.py", line 23, in <module>
    href=link.get("href") + ("\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have tried several things, but I need to append a line, any ideas? I'd appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: The error indicates that this line `link.get("href")` is returning a `None` value.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that link.get("href") has a value of None. So Python cannot perform the operand "sum" for None and a string. I suggest that you try debugging by printing the variable 'links' to check the value you are getting and why when you try the .get("href") you get None.